# Rails validation of image simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have that problem that my simple_form require both image file upload field and image url input.

How do I validate so that it is either the image fileupload field or the image url that should be requried not the both.

My View in another controller:

```
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :photo_attributes do |d| %>
<%= d.label :image, :label => 'Upload logo'  %>
<%= d.file_field :image, :label => 'Image'  %>
<%= d.input :image_url, :label => 'Billed URL' %>
<% end %>
```

My photo model:

```
require 'open-uri'

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :virksomhed
  attr_accessor :image_url

  has_attached_file :image,
                  :url  => "/public/images/billeder/photo/:id/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:basename.:extension"

  before_validation :download_remote_image, :if => :image_url_provided?

  validates_presence_of :image_remote_url, :if => :image_url_provided?, :message => 'is invalid or inaccessible'

private

  def image_url_provided?
    !self.image_url.blank?
  end

  def download_remote_image
    self.image = do_download_remote_image
    self.image_remote_url = image_url
  end

  def do_download_remote_image
    io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
    def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
  rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
  end

end
```

Comment: You want to validate this in a model, so when user submits your form you get back to him with error message that he can't do both or you want this "live", using javascript, so when user tries to put url in your form after he selected some image, you inform him that he should "decide"?

Comment: Is I want to validate that the user cannot use both, but 1 field is required now simple_form require both fields

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Model or view?

Answer (score 2):

The correct form is:
:with => %r{.(png|jpg|jpeg)$}i,

Otherwhise it will allow file.git.something

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about marking fields required in the view, SimpleForm marks each field as required (*) by default. It says so in the readme, complete with an example on how to override this (required => false).

In your model, I would do something like:

```
validate_presence_of :file_field, :unless => :image_url_provided?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
  with: %r{\.gif|jpg|png}i,
  message: 'must be a url for gif, jpg, or png image.'
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to say here Aman? It doesn't appear to contribute to the question. Please elaborate.